# Linq method for creating a sequence of separate objects?

Tags: c#, linq

I must be reinventing the wheel here - but I've searched and I can't find anything quite the same...

Here's my code for creating a sequence of zero or more objects that have a default constructor:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CreateSequence<T>(int n) where T: new()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        yield return new T();
    }
}
```

My question is quite simple: Is there a Linq equivalent of this I should be using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
Enumerable.Range(1,count).Select(_ => new T());
```

`Enumerable.Range` will give you the current number from the specified range as parameter, but you can simply ignore that (named as `_` in the example).

Comment: Many thanks. I timed this and (in release builds) this is significantly faster than my hand-rolled approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is: `var items = Enumerable.Repeat(new YourClass(), 10);`

Comment: This returns *the same item* 10 times, not 10 different items.

Comment: Thought of that first, too, but that will create a new item once and use that all the time, and he wants separate objects.